# Does Windows 10 have a DNS spoofing protection?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, dns, microsoft-edge, spoofing

I am trying to use my hosts file to check up on a server I'm trying to migrate before I'll change the actual dns. The thing is the browsers ignore my hosts file entries that do not use reserved addresses (like LAN, localhost or all-zero).

I've tried installing a localhost DNS server, added the IPs there, and for a few visits to the domain some browsers worked, and not they don't. Does windows have some kind of anti-spoofing mechanism? I've tried Firefox, Edge, IE, Brave. All with the DNS settings set properly to use the hosts file (like no DNS over HTTPS, network.dns.offline-local, etc).

Any ideas? This is new to me, and really bothering my working process.

Comment: There are many ways to spoof DNS and Microsoft tends to get new ways patched so they dont work anymore, here is an example>>>>>https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/security-updates/securityadvisories/2008/956187

Comment: Anyway to make it work as expected? I am suspecting the problem is with the browsers. The first visit to the site works, afterwards it "locks" to the real IP, while still displaying the "spoofed" IP as the remote address in the Developer Tools.

Comment: Are you sure its not just failing because the browser loads from cache? Have you done ipconfig /flushdns then refresh the browsercache? that is usually enough for me to use the hosts file.

Comment: Yes, I have deleted the browser cache, flushed the dns cache, etc. The fact is I can see the spoofed address in the developer tools (as I've stated in a previous comment), but the browsers (all of them, including chrome) only show the website from the "spoofed" server once, and afterwards it shows the one from the old server, while still maintaining the "spoofed" IP as the remote address.

Comment: Is IPv6 enabled in your network? Try to disable it.

Comment: @harrymc No, I do not have IPv6 support on my system. But I have also "spoofed" the server's  IPv6. didn't work